# Add custom colors to Xcode attributes inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a Swift class that extends UIColor and has functions like:

```
class func buttonShadowColor() -> UIColor
{
    return UIColor(red:0.74, green:0.74, blue:0.74, alpha:1)
}
```

Is there any way to add these colors to the "text color" (or any dropdown) in the attributes inspector so they can be used app wide from the storyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't a way to do this at the time you asked, but Xcode 9 adds named colors to asset catalogs, and they automatically appear in color properties in IB's inspectors. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the color only *once*, it will appear in the Recently Used Colors (the most recently used will appear on the left).

When you open the color picker, and select the Sliders tab, you can choose your desired color. When you're done, you can drag the color from the bottom left to one of the spots on the bottom right.

[image]

It is not possible to modify the list of basis colors (the one which starts with Dark Text Color).

Comment: Thank you.  That's a great solution.  I'm slightly color blind so I'd love a way to modify the list with glorious words - but this is a great alternative in lieu of that.